# Are there times in which an empty string is not equal to an empty string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I just seen this code snippet: `'' === '' ? null : ('' === '*' ? '*' : ('').split(','));`

Is there ever a time in which `'' === ''` is not true?

Comment: No, the empty string is always `===` to the empty string. You may be looking at code that was generated by a template mechanism.

Comment: The code doesn't make sense. It'll **always** return `null`. It is same as `true ? null : (You can do anything here, this doesn't even matter)`

Comment: That's what I thought, just making sure.

Comment: *Where* did you find this snippet?

Comment: @Shelby115 might be worth checking through older versions. Someone may have removed something with the intent of adding it back, but forgetting to do so.

Comment: Is it perhaps rendered code from a server side language, where it might originally have read, for example, `'__token__' === '' ? null : ('__token__' === '*' ? '*' : ('__token__').split(','));`, and therefore might be different at runtime?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly That is my guess, it's probably either there from old changes or to be edited in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there ever a time in which `'' === ''` is not true?

No, there is not.

This whole code snippet doesn't make too much sense, my guess would be that it is dynamically generated code and the string literals are filled in with some kind of templating mechanism - in this case they were filled with the empty string. Of course the conditions should better have been evaluated in the generator, but maybe the used engine didn't support this.